# php multiply strange integer overflow behavior

Tags: java, php, integer-overflow

In scala(java)

```
scala> 8218553819005469347L * 31
res75: Long = -3479248642764172867
```

But in php (5.5 / 64bit linux system)

```
<?php
echo (int)(8218553819005469347 * 31);
```

it prints **-3479248642764177408**

How to make php return same result as java.

Comment: I'm sorry, is Java and Scala interchangeable?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils scala and java have the same behavior here.

Comment: For the answer: Java Programmer need to read php Stuff and php Programmer need to read Java Doc... :)

Comment: `echo ((8218553819005469347 * 31) > PHP_INT_MAX) ? -PHP_INT_MAX : (int)(8218553819005469347 * 31);` perhaps? (untested)

Comment: So then *every* language that targets the JVM would then behave in the same way as well. You didn't include those languages or tags in your post. Point is, it might be a bit confusing the way it's written.

Comment: you can try: echo(int)(bcmul("8218553819005469347", "31")) (untested)

Comment: @MarkBaker That didn't work.

Comment: @YannSimon That did't work.

Comment: @YannSimon Was just testing that myself. I think that gives the right answer i.e. not the same wrong answer as java.

Comment: Not sure this is worth persuing as the question should have been _How do I make PHP get the same wrong answer as Java_. Not very productive really.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think java is reasonable, because it is strongly typed and did integer overflow as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function multiply31($num)  {
    return (int)(($num << 5) - $num);
}
```

Turn the `multiply` into `add` seems work.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably explain it best http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Also remember PHP has not been completely ported to 64bit see this little note in the sidebar of http://windows.php.net/

> x86_64 Builds
>
> The x64 builds of PHP for Windows should be considered **experimental**, and do not yet provide 64-bit integer or large file support. Please see this post for work ongoing to improve these builds.